# SVG Image not using parameter

Tags: php, image, svg

I am trying to create an SVG that takes in parameters, but for some reason it isn't applying them...

I have the following SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="1" height="1"
     xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     version="1.1">
    <defs>
        <ref id="paramFill" param="color" default="#000000"/>
        <ref id="paramOpacity" param="opacity" default="1"/>
    </defs>
    <polygon points="0,0 1,0 1,1 0,1"
         style="fill:url(#paramFill);fill-opacity:url(#paramOpacity);fill-rule:evenodd;" />
</svg>
```

The PHP that calls the SVG file looks like this, but when the image is displayed on the page I get an All black image. Why is it not using my parameters? only two colors should be created: `#9999FF` or `#FFFFFF` why is it using the default color?

```
<?php
// Inside a loop:
$color = ($chi == $i && $chj == $j) ? "#9999FF" : "#FFFFFF";
echo "<td style='background-image: url(/Websites/test.org/images/bg.svg?color=$color);'></td>";
```

Comment: Where are you getting the `<ref>` element from?  It is not a standard SVG element.

Answer (score 1):

You're stuffing a `#` into the url. Anything AFTER the `#` (your color values) is not going to be seen as a color value - it's going to be seen as a page anchor reference.

```
... url(/.....?color=#9999ff); ...
                     ^---anchor
```

The browser will be fetching

```
... url(/....?color=)
```

If it was an HTML page, then it'd try to scroll down to `<a name="9999ff">`, which on an svg isn't exactly possible.

Try `urlencode()`-ing at least:

```
...?color=%239999ff
          ^^^---url-encoded #
```

Comment: If I change my default from black to something else, it still shows as black... so there must be something else that is wrong...